# Пользовательский полигон ниже балунов при Yandex Map Kit for iOS

Tags: ios, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Использую Yandex Map Kit for iOS. На карту накладывают полигон (через Layer), но он получается поверх всего что есть на карте, в том числе поверх балунов (annotation).
Вопрос: как вставить layer или subview в карту, чтобы балуны были поверх всего остального? Чтобы они были поверх кастомно добавленного на карту полигона.

Состояния рисования на карте:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MVDrawState) {
   MVDrawStateReady = 0, //готов перейти к рисования полигона
   MVDrawStateDrawing,  //готов рисовать полигон
   MVDrawStateHaveDraw //имеем нарисованный полигон
};
```

Здесь находится карта и здесь идет вставка слоя полигона, нарисованного ранее на другой view:

```
//MainMenuViewController.m
@interface MainMenuViewController ()
//...
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet YMKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MVDrawView *drawView;
@property (nonatomic) MVDrawState drawState;
//...
@end

@implementation MainMenuViewController
...

#pragma mark - Draw & MVDrawViewProtocol
- (IBAction)drawButtonTouch:(id)sender {

    [self _takeBottomTableViewStateFor:sender];

    switch (self.drawState) {
        case MVDrawStateReady:
        {
            if (!self.drawView) {
            
                self.drawView = [[MVDrawView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mapView.frame];
                self.drawView.delegate = self;
            
            } else {
                [self _clearPolygon];
            }
        
            [self _removeAllObjectOnMap];
        
            [self.view insertSubview:self.drawView aboveSubview:self.mapView];
            self.drawState = MVDrawStateDrawing;
    }
        break;
    
    case MVDrawStateDrawing:
    {
        if (self.drawView) {
            [self.drawView removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.drawState = MVDrawStateReady;
        [self _getPointsFromModel];
    }
        break;
        
    case MVDrawStateHaveDraw:
    {
        [self _clearPolygon];
        [self.pointsPolygonInMap removeAllObjects];

        self.drawState = MVDrawStateReady;
        self.drawButton.buttonState = MVDrawStateReady;
        
        [self _reloadPoints];
        
    }
        break;
        
    default:
        break;
    }
}

- (void) setDrawState:(MVDrawState)drawState
{
    _drawState = drawState;
    self.drawButton.buttonState = drawState;
}

- (void) drawenPolygon:(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
{
    self.shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.mapView.layer];
    [self.shapeLayer copyShapeLayer:self.drawView.shapeLayer];
    [self.mapView.layer addSublayer:self.shapeLayer];
    
    [self _setupPointsPolygonInMap:bezierPath];
    
    [self.drawView removeFromSuperview];
    
    self.drawState = MVDrawStateHaveDraw;
    
    [self _reloadPoints];
 }

- (void) _setupPointsPolygonInMap:(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
{
    if (!self.pointsPolygonInMap) {
        self.pointsPolygonInMap = [NSMutableArray array];
    } else {
        [self.pointsPolygonInMap removeAllObjects];
    }

    if (!self.pointsPolygonRequest) {
        self.pointsPolygonRequest = [NSMutableArray array];
    } else {
        [self.pointsPolygonRequest removeAllObjects];
    }

for (NSValue *pointValue in bezierPath.points) {
    CGPoint point = pointValue.CGPointValue;
    
    NSDictionary *pointGeoRequest = [self _geoCoordinateInPoint:point];
    [self.pointsPolygonRequest addObject:pointGeoRequest];
    
    YMKMapCoordinate mapPointCoordinate = [self.mapView convertMapViewPointToLL:point];
    
    CLLocation *locationMapPoint = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:mapPointCoordinate.latitude
                                                              longitude:mapPointCoordinate.longitude];

        [self.pointsPolygonInMap addObject:locationMapPoint];
    }
}

- (void) _clearPolygon
{
    if (self.shapeLayer) {
        [self.shapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}

- (UIBezierPath *) _geoPointsToBezierPath
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    NSInteger indexStart = 0;
    NSInteger indexEnd = self.pointsPolygonInMap.count - 1;
    NSInteger indexCurrent = 0;

        for (CLLocation *pointLocation in self.pointsPolygonInMap)
        {
            CGPoint newPoint = [self _viewPointOnMapLatitude:pointLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                           longitude:pointLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        
            if (indexCurrent == indexStart) {
            [path moveToPoint:newPoint];
            
        } else if (indexCurrent == indexEnd) {
            [path addLineToPoint:newPoint];
            [path closePath];
        
        } else {
            [path addLineToPoint:newPoint];
        }
        indexCurrent ++;
    }
    return path;
}
```

В этом классе идет непосредственное рисование полигона пользователем:

```
//MVDrawView.h
@protocol MVDrawViewProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) drawenPolygon:(UIBezierPath*)bezierPath;
@end
 
@interface MVDrawView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MVDrawViewProtocol> delegate;


//MVDrawView.m
@interface MVDrawView()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
@end

@implementation MVDrawView

#pragma mark - Init
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
       [self _init];
   }
   return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if (self) {
       [self _init];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) _init
{
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

#pragma mark - Setups
- (void) setupShapeLayer
{
   self.layer.sublayers = nil;
   
   self.shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.layer];
   self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
   
   UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
   
   UIColor *fillColorStart = [UIColor clearColor];
   self.shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColorStart.CGColor;
   [self.layer addSublayer:self.shapeLayer];
}

#pragma mark - Touches
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch ​*>*​)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint pointTouchStart = [touch locationInView:self];
   
   self.bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
   [self.bezierPath moveToPoint:pointTouchStart];
   
   [self setupShapeLayer];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch ​*>*​)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint pointTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
   
   [self.bezierPath addLineToPoint:pointTouch];
   self.shapeLayer.path = self.bezierPath.CGPath;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch ​*>*​)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint pointTouchEnd = [touch locationInView:self];
   
   [self.bezierPath addLineToPoint:pointTouchEnd];
   [self.bezierPath closePath];
   self.shapeLayer.path = self.bezierPath.CGPath;
   
   UIColor *fillColorEnd = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
   self.shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColorEnd.CGColor;
   
   [self sendShapeLayer];
}

#pragma makr - Other

- (void) sendShapeLayer
{
   if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(drawenPolygon:)]) {
   [self.delegate drawenPolygon:self.bezierPath];
   }
   [self clearPolygon];
}

- (void) clearPolygon
{
   self.layer.sublayers = nil;
}
```

Comment: какой то код можно посмотреть?

Comment: Добавил пример кода в основное сообщение.

Comment: Едва ли код и вопрос ещё актуальны. Яндекс уже не поддерживает те версии МапКита, на которых это должно было работать. Стоит закрыть вопрос, наверное.